# Trying to integrate Spring MVC into existing Jersey API, 404 every time

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jersey, http-status-code-404, web.xml

I have an existing MVC application that I'm using as a guide to integrate Spring-mvc into this API. Everything is configured very similarly, but I can't get it to return a resource.

I figured this was possible because I've done something similar in C#. I'm using Intellij, so I thought simply adding the framework support would be sufficient

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.valassis</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.valassis.rest.client" />

    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Controller**

```
package com.valassis.rest.client;
import com.valassis.rest.DalimGetPropertyValues;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
@Controller
public class ClientController {
    String message = "Welcome to Spring MVC!";
    private String environment;
    private DalimGetPropertyValues properties = new DalimGetPropertyValues();
    {
        this.environment = properties.getEnvironemnt();
    }
    // Renders the Homepage
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showEnviornment(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", returnEnvironment());
        model.addAttribute("name", environment);
        return "index";
    }
    private String returnEnvironment() {
        String url;
        switch (environment) {
            case "dev5.0":
                url = "Currently in dev 5.0: " + properties.getDev2Url();
                break;
            case "newDev5.0":
                url = "Currently in newDev 5.0: " + properties.getNewDev2Url();
                break;
            default:
                url = "Currently in Prod 5.0: " + properties.getPrd2Url();
        }
        return url;
    }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Jersey RESTful Web Application!</h2>
    <p><a href="webapi/myresource">Jersey resource</a>
    <p>Visit <a href="http://jersey.java.net">Project Jersey website</a>
    for more information on Jersey!
</body>
</html>
```

**edit:**
This is the response I get from the server:
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: What's the *url* you are using?

Comment: Testing on Tomcat9, I've tried localhost:8090/test/

Comment: Try : `localhost:8090/your_proj_name/`

Comment: No luck.
Using the link I mentioned, the server returns:

org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: Use a different base path (url-pattern) for Jersey than `/*`. That is the main problem. It will take _all_ requests if you use this; even ones that are meant for your Spring URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the `dispatcher-servlet` in the `web.xml`. You have defined it in the `dispatcher-servlet` rather than the `web.xml`

This should be present in the `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Also add the following to indicate that the mvc application is annotation-driven in your dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: Oops! I had the labels reversed. This is how I have it in my project

Comment: Add the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to your dispatcher-servlet.

Comment: Yes, I have done that. I still can't figure out how to get to my view. I have seen some threads on here that site a jar called jersey-spring4. I added it to my pom and, after running the program, this was the error I got:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl
 org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.initialize(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:66)
 org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:98)

Comment: Not really sure why you need to add the *jersey* dependency.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need to add the `contextConfigLocation` in the web.xml